# Partitions on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: partitioning

I have a problem need help. I have two partitions called `Data` and `Sofware`.

Default, when I run command :

```
ls /media/my_username/
```

It's show empty (dont have any result on terminal)

but when I click on disk icon on launcher and run this command again, it's show two result.
Please let me know why ?

Comment: Are the partitions actually mounted when you first run the command? Sounds like they aren't, and opening them from the Launcher mounts them which then makes them appear in the listing.

Comment: Is there an easy how-to question about basic mounting? I tried a quick search but didn't see one.. maybe even a youtube video about the basics of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why does this happen?

Non-system partitions are not mounted on startup. Your system knows the partitions are present (the disk icon is shown) but they are not yet accessible through the filesystem.

Filemanagers automatically mount partitions when you click on them. They get mounted to `/media/username/...` That's why you see them only after you clicked on them, because nautilus mounted them when you clicked on them.

[More information on what mounting is](https://askubuntu.com/a/20681/172367)

## What can I do to see them immediately?

You can easily set a partition to automount on system startup. One of the ways is using the disks utility. [More information on how to set a partition to automount in the GUI](https://askubuntu.com/a/271527/172367)

Comment: @Ducnb, If this answer solved your problem, can you please mark it as accepted? This closes the question and rewards me for answering it correctly. Thanks!