# Full windows partition shows up as device in Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, file-sharing, umount

I recently installed Ubuntu to dual boot with Windows 8 on my HP Envy 15. When I go to my File Manager, it shows all the other partitions as removable devices that can be unmounted in the 'Devices' tab. Is this normal? While it's nice having access to all my Windows files, it seems very dangerous to accidentally be able to unmount a whole partition by the click of a button. Does anyone have insight to this, or at least ways that I can make sure I don't accidentally unmount?

Answer (score 1):

No need to worry.

1. It's absolutely normal to see any partitions including Windows ones under "Devices".
2. Mounting and unmounting are local to Ubuntu. Whenever you shut down Ubuntu, any mounted devices will be unmounted anyway, and when you go back into Windows the Windows partitions will be available to Windows.

For more information about mounting see:

[What does it mean to mount something?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20680/what-does-it-mean-to-mount-something)

Comment: Thanks! So I've seen instruction for making a shared drive between Ubuntu and Windows 8.1 - why should I do this when I can just access all my Windows files from Ubuntu?

Comment: Hmm that might be something specific to Windows 8, out of my area of expertise. If I answered your original question please could you accept it and then maybe post a new question specifically about file sharing with Windows 8.

Comment: It seems there are some specific difficulties with mounting Windows 8 partitions if they are hibernated. See this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation for a good explanation and workaround.

Comment: But apart from this, things should work normally http://askubuntu.com/questions/568577/pulling-files-from-a-windows-ntfs-partition-into-ubuntu