# Pulling files from a Windows NTFS partition into Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, windows, 14.10, ntfs

I'm a first time Ubuntu user. I'm on Ubuntu because I've wanted to migrate to a more stable OS for some time but have never had the impetus to jump that hurdle. However, I was away from home for 3 weeks and upon returning and powering on my computer, the system would get to the Windows loading screen and then freeze. I tried booting in repair mode and after a 14 hour attempt at scanning the disk and fixing errors, the system rebooted again. So I downloaded Ubuntu 14.10 on a separate machine, burned an ISO and booted from DVD on this machine. I had no problems getting Ubuntu up and running, and I did a side-by-side install with the active Windows installation.

At this point, what I'm trying to figure out is how to use Ubuntu to access the Windows partition of my harddrive in order to pull some documents over. I have most of my stuff backed up on an external 1TB drive, but there are a few recent files that haven't been backed up that I'd strongly like to get at. I really do not know what I'm doing with Ubuntu. If someone could point me to a useful guide that would be appreciated. My attempts at searching for such a guide have thus far been fruitless...perhaps I'm not using the proper terminology in my queries?

Many thanks for your kind assistance!

Blessings,

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At this point, what I'm trying to figure out is how to use Ubuntu to access the Windows partition of my harddrive in order to pull some documents over

Ubuntu will gladly mount ANY Windows partition by default. If it did not automatically open up nautilus and click on the partition and it will mount. Unless the disk is in an unsafe state; in that case you need to fix that 1st ( [Unable to mount NTFS hard drive partition "The disk contains an unclean file system"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/439634/unable-to-mount-ntfs-hard-drive-partition-the-disk-contains-an-unclean-file-sys) )

Example with the Windows installation (ie. C:):

[image]

You can drag+drop documents from Windows into Ubuntu (ie. into ~/Documents/ or ~/Downloads/.

Comment: I can't see the photo...says 404 not found. I appreciate your attempt to help, but a.) I don't know what Nautilus is...do you mean the thing labeled "Files" on the launcher? And I don't see anything under there about my C: drive from my Windows install at all, safe or otherwise.

Comment: @1John5vs7 Yes Nautilus is our "files" manager ;) It will not be called C: but someonething like "reservered space" or "xxxGb Volume".

Comment: Ok, thakn you Rinzwind. That is helpful. I'll see what I can do, but it may be that the disk was damaged somehow. I don't know how that could be since it was just fine when I left for vacation. I turned the comp off and unplugged it from the power source JUST IN CASE. I come back, and voila, it won't boot. Never again...glad I switched to Ubuntu.