# Using the terminal, how can I see the directory (and files) in an external HDD attached via USB port?

Tags: hard-drive, directory

Using the terminal, how can I see the directory (and files) in an external HDD attached via USB port?  (I am a beginner so would appreciate simple instructions.  I have tried to find the answer through "search" - there are similar questions with answers that I tried to bend to my needs but could not - sorry).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The topic that you're looking for is [mounting](https://askubuntu.com/q/20680/295286) . In the file manager you just click on the button to open it or detach the drive, but behind the scenes it uses `udisksctl` . Big advantage of this command is that it mounts as your user, and you don't have to specify whole lot of options, unlike the classic `mount` command.

For instance, to mount your usb drive, find device path with either `lsblk` or `sudo blkid` and then mount like so, for example,

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb1
```

Of course remember to replace `sdb1` with the actual device name you want to mount.

Once the device is mounted successfully, it will be reported where it is mounted. For example,

```
skolodya@ubuntu:$ udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb5
Mounted /dev/sdb5 at /media/xieerqi/0ca7543a-5463-4a07-8bbe-233a7b0bd625.
```

Then you could navigate to `/media/$USER/folder-name` and start exploring files and folders

Comment: It just tells me that the disk is not mountable filesystem. The disk works just fine, I just used it on another linux machine.

Answer (score 15):

USB media are normally mounted at `/media` go there in your terminal with `cd /media && ls` now you should see all storage mounted in that directory. If your device is in the list use `cd` to change in that directory and use `ls` or `ll` to list the files in your hdd.

If the hdd is not listed open your file Browser and use`ctrl+ l` to go in the adress bar. There you can see the path of your hdd.

Comment: Thank you - I really appreciate your help.  Unfortunately mine was not listed under media.

Comment: I just plugged in my USB external drive and was wondering about the same question. It took a minute or so until it showed up in <pre>media</pre>.

Comment: It's /media only for "normal" USB (USB stick or drive) . If you connect a smartphone per USB it appears in /run/user/<UID>/gvfs/. In this case some other commands are used for mounting than udisksctl: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/mounting-mtp-devices.

Answer (score 5):

Just a small addition to previous answer : 
If you started on a command line machine, or a headless system (like a rpi for example), device will probably not mount automatically.

You then should first search for his device name (`sudo fdisk -l`) and then mount it in an empty folder (`sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/myNewlyCreatedFolder`)

Answer (score 0):

`sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/root` lets you mount, but you don't have permission to copy it to another place yet

To do that follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23520744/cp-failed-to-preserve-ownership-error-when-mounted-manually

TLDR: mount using this `sudo mount -o uid=1000,gid=1000 /dev/sdc1 /mnt/boot` and copy using `sudo cp -Rrf --preserve=all <source> <destination>`