# Why unmount a partition before overwriting the disk?

Tags: mount, format, dd, umount

[How to create a bootable Ubuntu USB flash drive from terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal)

Why do guys here use `umount` first? I assume USB flash drive should be formatted first, so does `umount` format the disk, or just detach mounted device so it can be safely removed if another process isn't using it?

Answer (score 10):

`umount` un-mounts file systems.

This is needed here because it would be bad if you overwrote the partition while it is still mounted and possibly accessed by any application. You'd get errors.

See `man umount` for more information about the command.

Comment: Yes, but why did they in linked post unmounted plugged device, made new folder with the same name they deleted, and used dd after all?
Were eventually existed data from that device lost? Was it shortcut for formatting? - that is what confuses me.

Comment: I'm curious if writing to an unmounted device also bypasses write cache

Comment: @MilosKalicanin they didn't delete or make any new folder. /dev/sd? is the name of the device. no formating is necessary, `dd` is a copy program, similar to "burning a CD". the formating, file structure etc is copied from the image file used as input.

Answer (score 7):

Please correct me if I do not use the most appropriate terms here.

Within Linux/Ubuntu all devices are represented as files under the directory `/dev`. In the [first answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/377561/566421) of the linked question `umount` is used to detach certain device from the file-system in use, thus you can manipulate the entire device as pure file (`/dev/sd?`) without limitations. Then the command `dd` is used to copy the content of the input file `image.iso` file as content of the output file `/dev/sd?`.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/738902/566421) I found a better explanation provided by [Colin Ian King](https://askubuntu.com/users/26614/colin-ian-king):

> If you write data to the 'raw' block device while a filesystem on this
>   device is still mounted then the kernel will have problems when
>   updating the trashed file system.  For example, the kernel will
>   periodically flush dirty data back to the mounted device, or may do
>   file lookups.  If the underlying block device has been fundamentally
>   changed then the kernel will find issues this can lead too kernel OOPs
>   messages or even halt on BUG_ON() checks.  So always unmount the
>   filesystem before changing the underlying data on the block device.

Comment: "They detached certain device using umount in order to manipulate the entire device without limitations." - That's exactly how I understood.