# New to Ubuntu partitioning: Can someone explain mounting and basic partitioning?

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

So, I love Ubuntu, but I think I'm a bit lost when it comes to all the technical details of partitioning. I don't really understand what mounting is, and that may have led to my current issue. I have / mounted on it's own partition (from the advice of a lot of people), and the rest on whatever is left of my SSD. However, I didn't allocate enough space to begin with, so I needed to resize the partitions, and after an hour of booting issues, I got it to boot, but I don't know why. Also, I had to delete my swap partition so that I could allocate more space to "/". Now when I boot, Ubuntu takes much, much longer, and I'm not sure why. Is it because my swap partition is at the end of my GParted screen? Should I even have separate partitions if everything is housed on the SSD?

Can anyone give me a basic ELI5 on all of this stuff, or at least point me somewhere where I can learn more about it? It feels like a necessary thing to understand to work with Linux in general, and I'd like to know what I'm doing instead of blindly following what the internet tells me to do.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean to mount something?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20680/what-does-it-mean-to-mount-something)